# How do you divide each element in a list by an int?

Tags: python

I just want to divide each element in a list by an int.

```
myList = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
myInt = 10
newList = myList/myInt
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I understand why I am receiving this error. But I am frustrated that I can't find a solution.

Also tried:

```
newList = [ a/b for a, b in (myList,myInt)]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Expected Result:

```
newList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

**EDIT:**

The following code gives me my expected result:

```
newList = []
for x in myList:
    newList.append(x/myInt)
```

But is there an easier/faster way to do this?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be to use list comprehension:

```
myList = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
myInt = 10
newList = [x / myInt for x in myList]
```

or, if you need to maintain the reference to the original list:

```
myList[:] = [x / myInt for x in myList]
```

Comment: given a static list size, would either of these methods be faster than [mylist[0]/myint,mylist[1]/myint]

Comment: @user1938107 almost certainly not, but this is also the kind of micro optimization you should avoid anyway.

Answer (score 98):

The way you tried first is actually directly possible with [numpy](http://numpy.org):

```
import numpy
myArray = numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
myInt = 10
newArray = myArray/myInt
```

If you do such operations with long lists and especially in any sort of scientific computing project, I would really advise using numpy.

Comment: I know this is an old reply but for anyone still reading it:
keep in mind that when using numpy.array you should specify the type for example `numpy.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90], dtype='f')`for loat. Otherwise dividing by 3 would give you just 3 as the result instead of 3.333..

Comment: @RichardBoonen in this case the OP wanted to do int division, but if you want to do float division, you're right, you have to specify the type to numpy. Or put a single float in the list: ``numpy.array([10.,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])``

Answer (score 28):

```
>>> myList = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
>>> myInt = 10
>>> newList = map(lambda x: x/myInt, myList)
>>> newList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Do you think map is better than list comprehension in this case?  I am just wondering as I would of gone for list comprehension, as it is easier to read.

Comment: @AndrewCox I prefer map (coming from a non python background). List comprehension seems to be cleaner to me too, so you should probably go with that.

Comment: Do you know if this is faster than the solution soulcheck and berkantk posted?

Comment: @Casa: Someone tested this at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247490 .  The conclusion seems to be that list comprehensions win, in this particular case.

Comment: Nowadays `map()` returns a map object, so if you want a list you have to explicitly say `list()`. So in this case: `newList = list(map(lambda x: x/myInt, myList))`

Answer (score 15):

The abstract version can be:

```
import numpy as np
myList = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
myInt = 10
newList  = np.divide(myList, myInt)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
myList = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
myInt = 10
newList = [i/myInt for i in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myInt=10
myList=[tmpList/myInt for tmpList in range(10,100,10)]
```

Comment: Could you write shorter?

Answer (score 0):

I was running some of the answers to see what is the fastest way for a large number. So, I found that we can convert the int to an array and it can give the correct results and it is faster.

```
  arrayint=np.array(myInt)
  newList = myList / arrayint
```

This a [comparison](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy58YlFVw) of all answers above

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
myList = random.sample(range(1, 100000), 10000)
myInt = 10
start_time = time.time()
arrayint=np.array(myInt)
newList = myList / arrayint
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList = np.array(myList) / myInt
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList = [x / myInt for x in myList]
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
myList[:] = [x / myInt for x in myList]
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList = map(lambda x: x/myInt, myList)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList = [i/myInt for i in myList]
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList  = np.divide(myList, myInt)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
start_time = time.time()
newList  = np.divide(myList, myInt)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [2,4,8]  
new_list = [x//2 for x in list]  
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: using `x//2` does an integer division