# python: dividing a number by a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried the top two solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244915/how-do-you-divide-each-element-in-a-list-by-an-int) and the bottom solution since it dealt with numpy but nothing worked.

I wanted to take 80.0 divided each element of my array name that a new array dx.

```
import numpy

L = 80.0
N = []


for n in range(-4, 10):
    N.append(str(2 ** N))


N = np.array([N])
```

This is the set up.  So what I have tried is:

1. `dx = L / N`
2. ```
   dx = map(lambda x: L / x, N)
   dx = np.array([dx])
   ```
3. Lastly, keeping N as a list and keeping N as a numpy array and doing

   ```
   dx = [x / N for x in N]
   dx = np.array([dx])
   ```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a post that helped or anything in the documentation.  What can I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: why do you cast your int into str ?

Comment: @georgesl I thought it had to be a string to go into a list.

Comment: Nope, list can support any `type`, also different ones in the same list.

Comment: Further, this would give you a numpy array of strings, which cannot be divided with ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code contains several bugs and you have a lot of unnecessary casts, but however: why don't you try this with numpy directly?

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np

L = 80.0
N = 2 ** np.arange(-4, 10, dtype=np.float64)
dx = L / N
```

gives you the expected result

```
array([  1.28000000e+03,   6.40000000e+02,   3.20000000e+02,
         1.60000000e+02,   8.00000000e+01,   4.00000000e+01,
         2.00000000e+01,   1.00000000e+01,   5.00000000e+00,
         2.50000000e+00,   1.25000000e+00,   6.25000000e-01,
         3.12500000e-01,   1.56250000e-01])
```

Btw. you can also implicitly force the `dtype` to be `float` when using dots:

```
N = 2 ** np.arange(-4., 10.)
```

Comment: Thanks.  You have an extra r in `arange`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a single line using List comprehensions.

```
In [8]: N=[80.0/(2**n) for n in range(-4,10)]

In [10]: print N
[1280.0, 640.0, 320.0, 160.0, 80.0, 40.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.15625]
```

You can avoid using Numpy for such tasks.

The for loop equivalent of this would be (without preallocating N):

```
In [11]: N=[]

In [12]: for n in range(-4,10):
   ....:     N.append(80.0/(2**n))
   ....:     

In [13]: print N
[1280.0, 640.0, 320.0, 160.0, 80.0, 40.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25, 0.625, 0.3125, 0.15625]
```