# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, function, error-handling, typeerror

I got the below error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

How do I solve this problem? Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
def func(xdata_1,cc,dd,gg):
    return cc*(xdata_1**(dd))*
           (10**(-1.572*gg*( (185/((xdata_1/420)**2 + (420/xdata_1)**2 + 90 )) )

params,pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata_1,ydata_1,
                        sigma=err_1, absolute_sigma=True)

fc_1 = func(xdata_1, *params)
```

Comment: It sounds like one of the arguments being passed to `func` is a list.  So, figure out which one (you can just print them before calling `func`), and then fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [so many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unsupported+operand+type%28s%29+for+%2F%3A+%27list%27+and+%27int%27+)

Comment: Your code is not even sintactically correct, it can't possibly raise a TypeError.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8244915/21227293 to see how to divide a list with an integer.

Answer (score 7):

Check data type of all variable i.e. `xdata_1`,`cc`,`dd`,`gg`

**1. How to check type of variable**:

Use 'type` inbuilt function to get type of variable.

**Demo**:

```
>>> d
[1, 2, 3]
>>> type(d)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

**2. About Exception**:

This exception come when we operate `/` operation on `list` and `int` variables.

**Demo**:

```
>>> d = [1,2,3]
>>> d/4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
>>>
```

**3. Give input**:

Best to provide input details in the question i.e. value of `xdata_1` and `params`, so we can give you where code is wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Calculate the mean of two arrays `num1` and `num2`

```
p=[x / l for x in sum1]
print(p)
for ele in range(0,len(p)):
  total=total + p[ele]
print(total)
```

The answer is 3.5, which is indeed the mean of the two arrays or list `num1` and `num2`.

The full code:

```
num1=[1,2,3]
num2=[4,5,6]
total=0
sum1=num1+num2
print(sum1)
l=len(sum1)
print(l)
p=[x / l for x in sum1]
print(p)
for ele in range(0,len(p)):
  total=total + p[ele]
print("MEDIAN is",total)
```

Which outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
6
[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 0.8333333333333334, 1.0]
MEAN IS 3.5
```

Comment: Please review [answer] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1030169)